# "BACKUP" is not valid at this position

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I'm creating how to create a Database and made a very simple code following W3Schools tutorials, however I can't seem to backup my database.

```
CREATE DATABASE testdb
BACKUP DATABASE testdb
TO DISK = 'E:\database';
```

I get this error:

```
"BACKUP" is not valid at this position, expecting EOF, ';'

13:19:03    CREATE DATABASE testdb BACKUP DATABASE testdb TO DISK = 'E:\';  Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'BACKUP DATABASE testdb TO DISK = 'E:\'' at line 2  0.000 sec
```

I tried to do it step by step, all together (as shown above), etc, but I always get this error.
Thank you!

Comment: Are you referring to https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_backup_db.asp? That pertains to *SQL Server* (a Microsoft product), not MySQL!

Comment: The standard backup solution for MySQL (at least with community edition) is the [mysqldump](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html) utility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Such a comand doesn't exists in mysql

see [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-backup-excerpt/5.7/en/backup-methods.html) what us possible in MySQL like OUTFILE and mysqldump

You problably copied this form another rdms